# ArcSDE - How to edit mosaic dataset

Tags: arcgis-10.0, raster, arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning

I have a mosaic dataset (Raster) in an SDE database. As expected, when I click start editing, ArcMap says that I have to do "Register as Versioned" before, but I can't have a mosaic dataset in a Feature Dataset. Can I?? Can I register this mosaic dataset as registered in another way?

Normally, when a mosaic dataset is in an File geodatabase, you can start an edit session and edits the Boundary and the Footprint. I just want to do the same operation but with my mosaic dataset located in an ArcSDE server.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Thanks!

Please note: If it can be useful, I use direct connections to my SDE database.

Comment: your problem may be solve by using raster catalog . i think your problem is like this :http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/52312-SDE-Raster-Catalog   but you are using mosaic dataset .

Comment: Are you still trying to resolve this at ArcGIS 10.0 or a later version?

Comment: I haven't tried this with ArcMap 10.1 or 10.2, in my current task I don't work with mosaic dataset. In 10.0, I gave up and I edited the Footprint in a file geodatabase and after replace the Mosaic dataset in ArcSDE!

Answer (score 1):

I know that's an old question and it might have been answered elsewhere. However, if you need to edit footprints shapes and attributes or boundaries shapes and attributes in mosaic dataset, you need to register those objects as versioned using the register as versioned tool. It works for me at 10.2.1, but I suspect it works in older versions too.